# I would need to implement admob on my webview app

Tags: webview, admob, android-webview

How can I initialize advertising when a certain URL is visited? Can I use the initialize() method by calling it from a web page (URL load)? I cannot show Google Adsense advertising in my app because I have read that it violates the program policies. Website was implemented in php. Thanks in advance